# How to create a shared access signature with a stored access policy for an Azure Blob container in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azureportal

I read about shared access signatures generated with stored access policies for Azure Storage from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy).

I also read how to create this shared access signature with stored access policies for Azure Storage using PowerShell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-create-stored-access-policy-and-shared-access-signature).

However, I want to do the above using Azure Portal. I know how to generate an ad-hoc shared access signature. I also know how to create a stored access policy for a container in my Azure Blob.

How do I create a shared access signature with a stored access policy for an Azure Blob container in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> How do I create a shared access signature with a stored access policy
>   for an Azure Blob container in Azure Portal?

Simple answer to your question is that as of today you can't create a shared access signature (SAS) using a stored access policy in Azure Portal. This feature is not there yet. In fact, feature to create a SAS on a blob container is not there on the portal as of yet. You could only create account level SAS using Azure Portal.

If you need to create a SAS on a container using a stored access policy, please use Microsoft Storage Explorer tool (or any other storage explorer tool that has support for blobs management). Using this tool you will be able to specify a stored access policy when creating a SAS on the container.

Comment: This answer is still valid. You have to use the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to handle all the details in regards of SAS + Stored Access Policy.

Comment: Small update: it is now at least possible to create a SAS on a blob container, however still not using the access polilcy.

Answer (score 24):

[Preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/storage-explorer-preview-now-available-in-azure-portal/) of **Storage Explorer** is now available in Azure portal.

You can [generate SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs) for a container by `right clicking on the container` and select `Get Shared Access Signature` like we do in Storage Explorer using the preview

[image]

Comment: I could only create the SAS in the traditional view: Overview > Containers. Right-click the container and choose Access Policy. Create the policy. (I was only able to create an access policy based on date, didn't see a way to control based on IP address, etc.) Then I went to the Storage Explorer > Right-click container and chose "Get Shared Access Signature." Choose the one you just made above, then Create. That will get you the link to use.

Comment: This worked for me. It doesn't let you specify an IP address, sadly.

Comment: This works only on Azure BLOB at hte moment, not on ADLS Gen2

Comment: Worked for me for blob, no further selections (other than timezone) but what's been selected for the policy

Comment: For whatever reason, they removed the function of generating SAS based on access policy created in this PREVIEW feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do in the portal now.

1. Navigate to the container in your storage account
2. Select **Shared access tokens**
3. Use **Account key** signing method
4. Select the stored access policy to use for creating the SAS

Note: You won't be able to modify the permissions or the start/end dates since the stored access policy defines those.

[image]